# Ruby Prawn how to show images in two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I've got an array of pictures, that i want to iterate and show in 2 column table like so:

[image]

but so far i'm getting this:

[image]

using this code:

```
@conclusion.assets.each do |f|
  image f.picture.path
  move_down 10
end
```

Comment: any clues ???  i've found table in prawn, which accepts multidimentional array, but not able to iterate through

Answer (score 3):

Yay! got it working, code:

```
column_box([0, cursor], columns: 2, width: bounds.width) do
  @conclusion.assets.each do |f|
    image f.picture.path
    move_down 10
  end
end
```